# Why Won't Rmarkdown Document Knit to PDF?

Tags: r, r-markdown, miktex

At a loss here. Trying to get R Studio to knit my Rmarkdown document to a PDF. I've installed as much as I can figure out. What am I missing?

```
processing file: MyFirstRMarkdown3.Rmd
  |..........                                                            |  14%
  ordinary text without R code

  |....................                                                  |  29%
label: setup (with options) 
List of 1
 $ include: logi FALSE

  |..............................                                        |  43%
  ordinary text without R code

  |........................................                              |  57%
label: cars
  |..................................................                    |  71%
  ordinary text without R code

  |............................................................          |  86%
label: pressure (with options) 
List of 1
 $ echo: logi FALSE

  |......................................................................| 100%
  ordinary text without R code


output file: MyFirstRMarkdown3.knit.md

"C:/Program Files/RStudio/bin/quarto/bin/pandoc" +RTS -K512m -RTS MyFirstRMarkdown3.knit.md --to latex --from markdown+autolink_bare_uris+tex_math_single_backslash --output MyFirstRMarkdown3.tex --lua-filter "C:\Users\a12cof\AppData\Local\R\win-library\4.2\rmarkdown\rmarkdown\lua\pagebreak.lua" --lua-filter "C:\Users\a12cof\AppData\Local\R\win-library\4.2\rmarkdown\rmarkdown\lua\latex-div.lua" --self-contained --highlight-style tango --pdf-engine pdflatex --variable graphics --variable "geometry:margin=1in" 
! Sorry, but C:\Users\a12cof\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\miktex\bin\x64\pdflatex.exe did not succeed.

! The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again:

!   C:\Users\a12cof\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\miktex\log\pdflatex.log

Error: LaTeX failed to compile MyFirstRMarkdown3.tex. See https://yihui.org/tinytex/r/#debugging for debugging tips. See MyFirstRMarkdown3.log for more info.
Execution halted
```

Comment: It tells you to look in the `C:\Users\a12cof\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\miktex\log\pdflatex.log` file. Hopefully that file contains the information to get MiKTeX going again. Have you looked there? What does it say?

Comment: And is the problem specific to this document? Can you knit the sample document to PDF when you open a new rmarkdown file in RStudio? Can you knit to other output formats? HTML? Word? How are you knitting - R console or button in RStudio? Have you tried the other option?

Comment: Apologies for the delay in response - just wanted to let you know that I figured it out. Not entirely sure how, but checking in the file there that you noted, and installing a few updates + code did the trick (took me awhile to find updated installation package code, but it worked). Thanks!